# Соединение с интернетом

Tags: ubuntu

В общем есть `ubuntu` чистая ось, только поставил, при вставке кабеля пишет что мол подключено. Видит `WiFi` сети, при подключение запрашивает пароль, подключается к ним пишет сообщение об успешности, но соединения с интернетом нет, то есть просто, даже страничка в бразуере не грузиться.
ноут: `asus k52ju`
`Ubuntu 12.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите ваш роутер, раздает ли он айпишки, если нет, то в компе нужно в ручную настроить айпи адреса, шлюз и днс. Если роутер раздает айпи (Включен DHCP), то проверьте другим компьютером. Если и на другом компьютере такая ситуация, опять таки копайтесь в роутере.

Если есть возможность Выложите скрин интерфеса роутера. Разделы Wi-Fi, LAN, wan.

Comment: В доме 1пк, через лан вин7 все ок. Ноут вин7 WiFi, смарт wp8 WiFi все ок. Нокиа n9 WiFi все ок. Не работает лишь на бунте ноут, но он видит сети, подключается к ним, но доступа нет. Когда я напрямую кабель интернета выдераю и вставляю в ноут с настройками то все ок

Comment: YD_Gallery_20130804_134417.jpg: http://yadi.sk/d/HuOXNdfG7Y0l5YD_Gallery_20130804_134404.jpg: http://yadi.sk/d/RqxUDEr_7Y0lBYD_Gallery_20130804.jpg: http://yadi.sk/d/f5UKo7997Y0lH

Comment: http://yadi.sk/d/IEerhzdZ7Y1w6

Comment: раздал через телефон Wi-Fi на ноуте поймал, работает. При работе сроутером, доступа в сеть нет, но доступ к самому роутеру имееться, так же адрес пингуеться с другово ПК...

Comment: MAC-фильтр на роутере настраивали?

Comment: @Zerglyn не думаю что MAC-filter настроен, потому как все устройства работают, а в убунту не работает. Нужно посмотреть какой адрес получает ноутбук. Должны быть:192.168.0.2-100 (что-то между 2 и 100)255.255.255.0шлюз 192.168.0.1DNS 192.168.0.1

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай тоже вариант)))DHCP на роутере выключен, IP проводному соединению на Ubunta не прописан...МАС-фильтр, наверное, пришел в голову потому, что сам на хотспотах прописываю)))@avengerweb Ctrl+Alt+t и в консоли     ifconfig eth1Результат в студию. Конечно, если не разберетесь ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Надо одно содединение к сети использовать. А вообще очень общее описание ситуации. Пинги проходят? А с других устройств, например смартфона, можно выйти в интернет?